# Can I use common abbreviated words in my Statement of Purpose?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I know that since SOP is a formal letter, abbreviated words cannot be used. But can I use commonly used abbreviated words such as GPA, COVID-19, BSc, USA directly in my SOP? It seems that writing the full term every time will take a lot of words. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The general guidelines for use of abbreviations should apply, see here for example: https://www.proofreadingacademy.com/advice/proofreading-tips-abbreviations-in-ap-style/ . Nothing special about the statement of purpose in that respect.

Comment: Thank you for yoour suggestion

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that anyone would object to the abbreviations in your example, but use somewhat cautiously. Don't use chat-speak, lol, abbreviations, of course. You are probably writing to people a bit older than you are.

Comment: Yeah Thank you for your suggestion.....